# How to insert the value of input time to database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on an attendance system where user should specify his time in and time out using an `<input type="time">`, but then when I try to submit the form it keeps sending me an error

Here's a snippet of HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1" name="day1" class="date-field" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="time" id="day1-in" name="day1-in" class="time-field" title="Ex: 08:00 AM"></td>
    <td><input type="time" id="day1-out" name="day1-out" class="time-field" title="Ex: 05:00 PM"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ot-1-a" id="ot-1-a" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ot-1-b" id="ot-1-b" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ot-1-c" id="ot-1-c" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-hrs-served" class="dtr-field" name="day1-hrs-served" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-reg-ot" class="dtr-field" name="day1-reg-ot" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-reg-hol-ot" class="dtr-field" name="day1-reg-hol-ot" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-spe-hol-ot" class="dtr-field" name="day1-spe-hol-ot" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-reg-hol-ot-ot" class="dtr-field" name="day1-reg-hol-ot-ot" hidden readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="day1-spe-hol-ot-ot" class="dtr-field" name="day1-spe-hol-ot-ot" hidden readonly></td>
</tr>
```

Snippet of my PHP code

```
$day1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1']);
$day1In = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-in']); 
$day1Out = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-out']);
$day1HrsServed = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-hrs-served']);
$day1RegOT = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-reg-ot']);
$day1RegHol = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-reg-hol-ot']);
$day1SpeHol = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-spe-hol-ot']);
$day1RHOT = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-reg-hol-ot-ot']);
$day1SHOT = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day1-spe-hol-ot-ot']);

$daily = "INSERT INTO daily_records (ref_dtr, record_date, record_in, record_out, hrs_served, reg_ot, reg_hol, spe_hol, rh_ot, sh_ot) VALUES ($dtr_ref, $day1, $day1In, $day1Out, $day1HrsServed, $day1RegOT, $day1RegHol, $day1SpeHol, $day1RHOT, $day1SHOT)";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $daily)){
   echo "Records added successfully.";
} 
else{
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $daily. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

when I submit this form it throws an error

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO daily_records (ref_dtr, record_date, record_in, record_out, hrs_served, reg_ot, reg_hol, spe_hol, rh_ot, sh_ot) VALUES (5d7f686865d1a, 2019-09-01, 08:00 AM, 05:00 PM, 8.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00 AM, 05:00 PM, 8.00, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 0)' at line 4

I suspect that the problem is because of the input time, currently the `record_in` and `record_out` datatype is time and I also tried to change it to varchar but it still throws the error. Can someone point out my mistake or any suggestion to improve my code, thanks.

**UPDATE**
Because the input time I'm using is in 12 hr format, I used

```
$day1InCon = date('H:i', strtotime($day1In));
$day1OutCon = date('H:i', strtotime($day1Out));
```

to convert it to 24 hr format. There seems to be a problem in inserting 12 hr format in the database but I'm not sure.

Comment: *':00, 18:00, , , , 8.00, 1.00, 0, 0, 0, 0)'* I see commas with nothing between, it may be a part of your issue.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439

Comment: @KévinBibollet - I forgot to update the thrown error, those are from the checkbox values, I also tried removing them for the meantime but i still got the error

Comment: @Dharman i'll try to update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL values you must use quote(') for strings parameter.

Example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (name, surname, address) VALUES ( '" . $name . "', '" . $surname . "', '" . $address . "' )";
```

Comment: After formatting the hours, I still got an error and then I used single quote in `$dtr_ref` and it worked. Thanks